# RDP connection automation with Python

Tags: python, rdp

Can we automate the Remote Desktop connections with python script. As part of my work I need to open many RDP connections manually. From a list of IPs the code has open RDP session for each IP in the list.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/49273/supply-username-and-password-to-mstsc

Comment: My query is to automate RDP sessions, suppose if i give a list of IPs the script has to open the sessions for that IPs.

Comment: `mstsc --help` shows a dialog with command-line options, maybe some of those could be of help?