# Automate an RDP connection right after Windows instance turns on in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am performing some UI Automation on GCP using a Windows Server.

The process is as follows:

```
=> Machine Switches on at a defined time
=> RDP Connection to Machine
=> UI Interaction Script Runs on Startup
=> Process Ends
=> Machine Switches off at a defined time
```

All the components have been fulfilled except for automating the RDP connection in some way or other. I referred to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57250538/rdp-connection-automation-with-python) but didn't find much insights or documentations.

Does anyone know a way to Automate an RDP connection right after instance turns on in GCP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried using `startup-scripts` but no luck `IAP Desktop` didn't work due to scheduling as well. Finally Managed to solve it via using [Windows 10 Auto login](https://www.technipages.com/how-to-enable-auto-login-in-windows-10) settings. This skips login screen and the best part was that out of all the users, it allows you to login via user of your choice. After I Login to the system, I added a startup a `bat` file by running `shell:startup` and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

There is a windows application called [IAP Desktop](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iap-desktop#iap-desktop), using that you can manage multiple remote Desktop connection to Windows VM. While [connecting](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iap-desktop/wiki/Connecting-to-instances) to the VM you can save the credentials which will allow you to access the Windows VM using RDP just after boot on.

Also to automate the Windows password generation here is the documentation related to [1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/automate-pw-generation), inside of that document there are both options available automate or manually.

Comment: Hmm, I saw that... but it doesn't allow me schedule RDP... also my IP dynamically changes with each boot... how do I deal with that?

Comment: You can [reserve Static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) and [assigned static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#assign_new_instance) to the VM

Comment: Yes I know that but static IP has its own charges.

Comment: Yes, if you want to use a fixed IP for the VM then need to pay for that :)

Answer (score 0):

How are you deploying your startup script?

During the boot sequence, a script will either run before, after or during the boot process. By declaring [Windows-specific metadata keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_a_startup_script_for_windows_instances), you can run startup scripts after the instance turns on.

If that doesn't work, there is a paid [Cloud Automation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/partners/deploying-windows-rds-itopia#objectives) service that sounds like it will meet your requirements.